# Javascript make the ball move

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make the ball move when I press <kbd>space</kbd>, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

It is vanilla Javascript with createjs libary. Can anybody help me and give me a little hint?

```
window.addEventListener('load', preload);
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

var stage, queue;
var ball;
var paddle;
var settings = {
    lives: 3,
    points: 0,
    speed: 3,
    ballMovingSpeed: 7
}
var fingerDown = false;
var keys = {
    left: false,
    right: false,
    shoot: false
}
var ballSettings = {
    ballRadius: 10,
    dx: 2,
    dy: -2
}
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;



function preload() {
    "use strict";
    stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");
    queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(true);
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tickHappened);
    drawPaddle();
    drawBall();
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', keyUp);
}



function drawBall() {
    "use strict"
    ball = new createjs.Shape();
    ball.graphics.beginFill('red').drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
    stage.addChild(ball);
    ball.x = 400;
    ball.y = 535;
    canvasHeight += ballSettings.dy;
    canvasWidth += ballSettings.dx;

}

// paddle Movement
//--------------------------------*

function keyDown(e) {
    "use strict";
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
        keys.left = true;
        break;
    case 39:
        keys.right = true;
        break;
    case 32:
        keys.shoot = true;
        break;
    }
}

function keyUp(e) {
    "use strict";
    switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
        keys.left = false;
        break;
    case 39:
        keys.right = false;
        break;
    case 32:
        keys.shoot = false;
        break;
    }
}


function movePaddle() {
        "use strict";
    if (keys.left) {
        paddle.x -= settings.speed;
        if (paddle.x < 0 + paddle.regX) {
            paddle.x = 0 + paddle.regX;
        }
    } else if (keys.right) {
        paddle.x += settings.speed;
        if (paddle.x > canvasWidth - paddle.width + paddle.regX) {
            paddle.x = canvasWidth - paddle.width + paddle.regX;
        }
    } else if (keys.shoot) {
        console.log("shoot ball");
        if (canvasWidth + ballSettings.dx > canvas.width -   ballSettings.ballRadius || canvasWidth + ballSettings.dx < ballSettings.ballRadius) {
        ballSettings.dx = -ballSettings.dx;
    }
        if (canvasHeight + ballSettings.dy > canvas.height -  ballSettings.ballRadius || canvasHeight + ballSettings.dy <     ballSettings.ballRadius) {
            ballSettings.dy = -ballSettings.dy;
        }
    }
}

function tickHappened(e) {
    "use strict";
    movePaddle();
    stage.update(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to have your object move, you need a few things. First, you need to re-draw it, which you seem to have set to re-draw 60 times per second. Next, you have to update the position of your object. Your ball needs two things for that, a velocity X and a velocity Y. With each tick, you'll set the ball.x += ball.velX so that each time it'll move it's position along with it's moving velocity, and once it hits something just set the ball.velX = -ball.velX.

I'm not sure what project you're working on but I'm assuming it is somewhat similar to pong, if you'd like to review or use some of the code I used on my own pong game feel free - http://pongio.bitballoon.com/